# How to allow duplicates in an arrayList when using JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I keep getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity" even though I have the @Id set as true and I'm using a one to many relation on my variable.

Here are the classes which I'm trying to relate to one another:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "map_area")
public class MapArea extends BasicModel {
   @Id
   @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
   private String name;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "area", referencedColumnName = "name")
   public List<AlternativeAreaName> alternativeNames;

    public MapArea() {}

    public MapArea(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.alternativeNames = new ArrayList<>();
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alternative_area_name")
public class AlternativeAreaName implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = false)
    private String area;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String alternativeName;

    public AlternativeAreaName(){}

    public AlternativeAreaName(String area, String alternativeName) {
        this.area = area;
        this.alternativeName = alternativeName;
    }

}
```

I want to have JPA create another table that relates to this one simple based on the name variable but whenever I try to add to the list and save to the DB I get

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity

```
MapArea mapArea = new MapArea("example");
AlternativeAreaName altAreaName1 = new AlternativeAreaName("example", "alt example");
AlternativeAreaName altAreaName2 = new AlternativeAreaName("example", "alt example2");
mapArea.alternativeNames.add(altAreaName2);

mapAreaRepository.save(mapArea);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the `private String area` field as the primary key for entity AlternativeAreaName. So when you are trying to add

```
AlternativeAreaName altAreaName1 = new AlternativeAreaName("example", "alt example");
AlternativeAreaName altAreaName2 = new AlternativeAreaName("example", "alt example2");
```

Both of them have the same primary key. So it is throwing the above exception.

To generate the primary key for JPA entity, please check

- https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm

Comment: But I've told it it doesn't have to be unique. Isn't there a way to not have to generate a primary key? Seems a bit unnecessary since primary key doesn't have to be unique.

Comment: who said the primary key doesn't have to be unique? Also, how will you identify each row   in database without any unique column

Comment: So I added ```     @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id; ``` but now it's saying " org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value"